# how can i display users with specific role in my show.blade.php and must be approved?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display user with specific roles in my database
i have 3 roles vendor, customer and the administrator. I want to list vendors in my show.blade.php and must be approved by the admin

here is my controller

```html
  public function operators(){
        $users = User::all();
        return view('User::frontend.profile.show', compact('users'));
    }
```

and my view

```html
<div class="list-item">
                                <div class="row">
                                    @foreach($users as $user)
                                    @if (count($users)>0)
                                     
                                    <div class="page-profile-content page-template-content">
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-3">
```

Comment: How did you save the roles in db ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have additional data about your users available for display, and also to limit the users you are working with. The best place to apply these rules is at the time you query the database. I can't know exact syntax without knowing the details of your implementation, but something along these lines:

```
 $users = User::all();
```

Approved by the admin:
    Does this approval process equate to a bool column on the User table getting set to true? If not, it probably should. Then you can modify your query to something along the lines of:

```
 $users = User::where('is_approved', '=', 1)->get();
```

Now you are only loading the users you want to work with, which helps keeps the query as quick as possible and avoid the need to do any additional logical checks on the data as you display it.

For roles, you likely need to look in a different table in the database? Make sure you have the relationship defined on the model, and then you can add a `whereHas()` clause to your query as well.

```
  $users = User::where('is_approved', '=', 1)->whereHas('roles', function($query){ $query->where('name','=', 'vendor');})->get();
```

That gets hard to read on one line, but it can be made easier to read. This is the same query in a cleaner layout:

```
  $users = User::query()
     ->where('is_approved', '=', 1)
     ->whereHas('roles', function($query){ 
          $query->where('name','=', 'vendor');
     })
     ->get();
```

`roles` should equate to the name of the relationship on your user model, and `name` is the field within the roles table which has the name in.

WhereHas is explained in more detail at https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

There's also some good information at https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#retrieving-models with might be worth reviewing.

I hope this helps!